# ffmpeg Error: Too many packets buffered for output stream

Tags: npm, video, ffmpeg, node-modules

I am working on an electron app that uses ffmpeg, I am developing on a win10 machine so I am using command prompt and I have installed the npm package 'ffmpeg-ffprobe-static'. I can run ffmpeg commands in the terminal by calling the package like so:

```
C:\Users\martin\myproject\node_modules\ffmpeg-ffprobe-static>ffmpeg.exe -h
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
....
```

I have an ffmpeg command to combine two flac files into a single mp3 file that has been working fine until I encountered this error:

```
[mjpeg @ 0000022537ace640] bits 85 is invalid
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.
[libmp3lame @ 0000022537ac3480] 3 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

The same command works for other flac files, so there's something about these Billy Martin songs that can be played perfectly fine in vlc but cause ffmpeg to crash:

```
//running this command:


ffmpeg.exe -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\broken flac example\05 - Billy Martin - Phillie Dog.flac" -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\broken flac example\08 - Billy Martin - Stax.flac" -y -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k "G:\RenderTune broken files\broken flac example\COMBINED_FILES.mp3"


//results in this output:
[mjpeg @ 0000022537ace640] bits 85 is invalid
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.
[libmp3lame @ 0000022537ac3480] 3 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

I uploaded the broken flac files here: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/0v9hbfrap727y/broken+flac

If I run this same command with other flac files it works fine:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\5. Gossip.flac" -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\6. Let The Children Play.flac" -y -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\COMBINED_FILES.mp3"
```

I have tried adding `-max_muxing_queue_size 9999` to my ffmpeg command like many posts suggest but that does not fix it, does anybody know how to prevent this error?

**[edit]**
I tried one of the posted solutions:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\5. Gossip.flac" -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\6. Let The Children Play.flac" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\COMBINED_FILES.mp3"
```

which crashed with a different error:

```
[libmp3lame @ 000002453725f3c0] Queue input is backward in time.9x
... lots of these [mp3 @ ..] messages
[mp3 @ 0000024537344400] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 2449071 >= 2445999
[mp3 @ 0000024537344400] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 2449071 >= 2447151
[mp3 @ 0000024537344400] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 2449071 >= 2448303
[flac @ 00000245372d4140] invalid residual315.7kbits/s speed=59.7x
[flac @ 00000245372d4140] decode_frame() failed
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid data found when processing input
size=   24871kB time=00:10:37.09 bitrate= 319.8kbits/s speed=60.5x
video:0kB audio:24869kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.004673%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong involving the album art image. Ignore it by adding an output label to your concat filter output and only [mapping](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) the concatenated audio:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\5. Gossip.flac" -i "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\6. Let The Children Play.flac" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k "G:\RenderTune broken files\working flac example\COMBINED_FILES.mp3"
```

Otherwise the [default stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will choose the filter output plus the broken image causing the error shown in your question.

Comment: I did actually notice when I would play the audio files that the file's metadata album cover would not appear in VLC so that would make sense that the files have some corrupt metadata or something. I tried you command and it still seemed to fail now with this err ```[flac @ 00000245372d4140] invalid residual315.7kbits/s speed=59.7x
[flac @ 00000245372d4140] decode_frame() failed
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid data found when processing input``` (I Will update my question to include more info)

Comment: @Martin Works for me with `05 - Billy Martin - Phillie Dog.flac` and `08 - Billy Martin - Stax.flac`. Please provide the new input files that are failing.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem to me (afterwards says about broken flags but this is easily fixed by recodening again or by playing with settings).

Linux 21.04, ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 4.2.3

File example: [here](https://file.io/nCT5X7jO3F0Z) (for few days)

```
 ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i peta_alien.ogv  -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -max_muxing_queue_size 4000 peta_alien.avi
```